# Microsoft Azure : Add users and map them to a database + add database roles

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am brand new to Azure so please bear with me ...

Using export tool in SSMS I managed to copy all of my tables from local database to Azure.
Now the most important part, adding users and mapping them to a database is unexplained.Also adding roles to database.Maybe it is explained but I sincerely dont understand a word of it. Seen some movies on YouTube but they mostly deal with database creation. SSMS is virtually useless for the Azure task (Or at least I do not know how). Also I can not find any tool on Azure dashboard to do it with.

So can someone to me explain in plain english the functionality of this stuff. 
What I could fathom is that you need to add users first to the Master database. Ok, I add user with a query:

```
 CREATE LOGIN  USER1  WITH PASSWORD = 'AG123SAL#'
```

So the user is added to the Master database.

Now, how do I map this user to a certain database?
How do I set what he can do?
And how do I add roles to my database and add user to role ?
This is all very hard for a total newbie ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Contained user database model,instead of old model..The way to do this is to connect to database on which you are trying to provide access to a user and run

```
CREATE USER mary WITH PASSWORD = 'strong_password';
```

to provide permissions to this user

```
 ALTER ROLE dbmanager ADD MEMBER Mary;
```

[Microsoft recommends this model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff929188.aspx) ,when using SQLAzure since this is database as  a service..Below is a quote from microsoft on same

> As Microsoft evolves the SQL Database service and moves towards higher guaranteed SLAs you may be required to switch to the contained database user model and database-scoped firewall rules to attain the higher availability SLA and higher max login rates for a given database. Microsoft encourage you to consider such changes today.

If you are looking for old model of login-user based heirarchy,you can read below

**to create login:**

```
create login mary with password='password'
```

Now to map user to database,you need to create user and map to that login.Login to the database ,you want to provide permissions  and create user

```
create user marydb1 from login mary;
```

you also can assign roles as well

```
ALTER ROLE dbmanager ADD MEMBER Mary;
```

**Updated as per comment :**

create role

```
create role rolename AUTHORIZATION db_manager*;
```

*:this should be user has total permissions on the database..since we may use this as base

now add permissions to that role

```
grant select,update,delete to rolename;
```

now add users

```
ALTER ROLE rolename ADD MEMBER username;
```

Comment: Theres only 2 roles. How do you add a custom role?

Comment: @user763539:  See updated,please update the question as well

Comment: [There are more than two roles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this sql server authentication with Azure SQL Database tutorial

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-control-access-sql-authentication-get-started